# Add tooltip on append-icon using Vuetify (1.0.5)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to add a tooltip over the info icon. I am not able to figure out how can I do that. Help me out.

```
   <v-flex xs12 md6 class="add-col-padding-right">
    <v-text-field required
      label='Information'
      v-model='demo.information'
      :rules='nameRule'
      append-icon="info">
    </v-text-field>
   </v-flex>
```

[image: Image1]

Update

```
<v-flex xs12 md6 class="add-col-padding-right">
  <v-text-field required label='Information' v-model='demo.information' :rules='nameRule'>
   <template slot="append-outer">
    <v-tooltip right>
     <template v-slot:activator="{on}">
      <v-icon v-on="on">place</v-icon>
     </template>
     <span>tooltip!</span>
    </v-tooltip>
   </template>
  </v-text-field>
</v-flex>
```

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since append-outer-slot does not exist yet in Vuetify 1.0.5, you'll need to use CSS/Vuetify's flex utility classes to place the icon afterward.

```
  <v-flex xs12 md6 class="add-col-padding-right">
    <div class="input-container d-flex align-center">
     <v-text-field required label='Information' v-model='demo.information' :rules='nameRule'></v-text-field>
     <v-tooltip right>
      <v-icon slot="activator">info</v-icon>
      <span>{{demo.information}}</span>
     </v-tooltip>
    </div>
   </v-flex>
```

Here's a working example:  https://codepen.io/Qumez/pen/WNvNgJP

Comment: Please check the update section in the question. I did as you suggested but the icon doesn't show up.

Comment: You need to add "mdi-" in front of the word "place" (`<v-icon>mdi-place</v-icon>`). Source is the first paragraph on this page: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/icons

Comment: My mistake, I didn't regard version in this post. I've updated my answer and my CodePen link to use Vuetify 1.0.5.